# Samsung GT 15801 is not recognised by Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

I had tested my Android application in Samsung GT 15801 device using Eclipse. One day I needed to reinstall samsung Kies. After that I tried to install application using Eclipse it is not in the "connected device" list anymore.

Kies shows it's product number (GT 15801) but still I cannot access it inside Eclipse.

(I am using Windows 7)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay,I going answer my own question hope some body will find it helpful

Problem fixed when I updated my eclipse .It is happened because I have latest android sdk version( it folder structure is slight different than previous version adb is in platform tool folder) and my eclipse version is old it looks for adb in android-sdk-windows/tools 
actually it is in android-sdk-windows/platform-tools

U can check for the error by going through Window-->preference-->android-->SDk location

Thanks